# Liquibase change column type from Date to DateTime without deleting contained values

Tags: java, date, datetime, database-migration, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase for data migration.

I have a table named Document that already contains values.

My table Document contains columns(id, name, dueDate).
The dueDate column is of type Date and i want to change his type from DATE to DATETIME.

I have adopted the following strategy

1- create a new column duedatenew of type DATETIME

2- copy values from column duedate to duedatenew

3- delete column duedate

4- rename column duedatenew to duedate

as described in the following changeset

```
  <changeSet id="task-99" author="blaise">
        <addColumn tableName="document">
            <column name="duedatenew" type="DATETIME" />
        </addColumn>
        <update tableName="document">
            <column name="duedatenew" valueComputed="(SELECT duedate FROM document)" />
        </update>
        <dropColumn tableName="document" columnName="duedate" />
        <renameColumn tableName="document" oldColumnName="duedatenew"
        newColumnName="duedate" />
</changeSet>
```

but the execution of changeset always fails during the second step. the copy of data always fails.

How can i solve this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was watching the [column](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html) docs... It seems that `valueComputed` should point to a sql function, so a select query will not work...

But, according to [this](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/how-to-upate-a-field-from-another-fields-value), your best option is to use the `sql` Tag to execute the update as your want... Example:

```
<changeSet id="task-99" author="blaise">
    <addColumn tableName="document">
        <column name="duedatenew" type="DATETIME" />
    </addColumn>
    <sql>update document set duedatenew = duedate</sql>
    <dropColumn tableName="document" columnName="duedate" />
    <renameColumn tableName="document" oldColumnName="duedatenew"
    newColumnName="duedate" />
</changeSet>
```

Comment: thanks Carlitos for your answer. the solution that you proposed is what i adopted firstly and it works. but i wanted a way to use liquibase tags without writing sql.
In fact, i'm working in a company whose one of the principles is to write codes that does not depends on any DataBase, due to the fact that we use ORM for java object mapping. so our codes is supposed to work on any SGBD, that's why we avoid writing specific sql codes. so i wanted a way to use only liquibase tags in my changeSet to solve this problem.
Thanks for your answer. 
please do you know a way to avoid this sql ?

Comment: Not really (and I think you can't), @blaiso... However, if your write SQL standard, I don't see why you cannot use the SQL tag (using SQL Standard, you don't violate your company principles)... Would you mind accepting my answer as correct? Thanks!

Comment: OK, Thanks Very much Carlitos for your answer